# SQL query optimization for 1million record

Tags: mysql, sql

1) The below query is run over 1 Million records minimum. Right now it is giving results in `70ms to 1s`. Is the performance good. What is the ideal time in which the query should return results. (MySql InnoDB system) all columns are in same table

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    rgb
WHERE
    ((tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5
        AND r3 = 8)
        OR (r1 = 8 AND r2 = 5)
        OR (r1 = 5 AND r2 = 8)
        OR (r1 = 3 AND r2 = 8)
        OR (r1 = 5 AND r2 = 3)
        OR (r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5)
        OR (r1 = 8 AND r2 = 3))
order by case
    when
        (tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5
            AND r3 = 8)
    then
        1
    else 2
end
```

2) Can I have a lengthy condition in my WHERE clause? The entire data is to be scanned from a single table.

Comment: for R1, R2 and R3, are the values of 3, 5 and 8 the only possible values?  Or just the ones you are interested in.

Comment: How many rows does this query return (approximately)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to have a covering index for your query of ( r1, r2, r3, tcount )

and have the WHERE clause something like

```
where
       r1 in ( 3, 5, 8 )
   AND r2 in ( 3, 5, 8 )
   AND r1 != r2
   OR ( r1 = 3 and r2 = 5 and r3 = 8 and tcount = 16 )
```

Comment: @CuriousLajpat, just for grins, yes it worked, but how has this helped in performance even though it significantly shortened readability of where criteria.

Answer (score 3):

why not use this simpler one ? instead of using a bunch of `OR`s

```
  SELECT 
*
FROM
rgb
WHERE
((tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5
    AND r3 = 8)
    OR (r1, r2) IN ((8,5),(5, 8), (3, 8),(5,3),(3,5),(8,3))

order by case
when
    (tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5
        AND r3 = 8)
then
    1
else 2
end
```

Comment: +1 for `(r1, r2) IN ( ...)` - I didnt know that was possible :)

Comment: @SebastianH Thanks :) .yes its possible check this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=2/72132/4/0#!2/72132/4/0)

Answer (score 1):

SQL optimization depends in part on the distribution of your data. We cannot guess it, so we cannot answer what is the standard time for your request. But MySQL can do it for you. Use EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    *
FROM
    rgb
WHERE
    ((tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5
        AND r3 = 8)
        OR (r1 = 8 AND r2 = 5)
        OR (r1 = 5 AND r2 = 8)
        OR (r1 = 3 AND r2 = 8)
        OR (r1 = 5 AND r2 = 3)
        OR (r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5)
        OR (r1 = 8 AND r2 = 3))
order by case
    when
        (tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5
            AND r3 = 8)
    then
        1
    else 2
end
```

and get the execution plan. Then look for table scans and index scans, and consider changing indexes to avoid them. Sometimes, if the amount of rows returned in a query is high, a full table scan is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to optimize this query using indexes.  But, I think you can split it into two parts to get proper index usage:

```
(SELECT r.*
 FROM rgb r
 WHERE (tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5 AND r3 = 8)
) UNION ALL
(SELECT r.*
 FROM rgb r
 WHERE (r1 = 8 AND r2 = 5) OR
       (r1 = 5 AND r2 = 8) OR
       (r1 = 3 AND r2 = 8) OR
       (r1 = 5 AND r2 = 3) OR
       (r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5) OR
       (r1 = 8 AND r2 = 3)
)
order by (case when (tcount = 16 AND r1 = 3 AND r2 = 5 AND r3 = 8)
               then 1
               else 2
          end);
```

Next, create an index on:

```
create index rgp_r1_r1_r3_tcount on rgp(r1, r2, r3, tcount);
```

This index should work on both subqueries.  I don't think that MySQL is smart enough to use it on the original data, but that is also worth a try.